# How to store and then pass an arrayList of all checked Items (HashMap objects items) from a ListView in Android?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

Hey everyone I am new to Android programming and need some Help. I have a list view that consists of HashMap objects. These hashMap objects can be selected by checking a check box. (So basically I have a check box list). What I am trying to do is Store all the HashMap objects (or items) that are checked in the ListView in an ArrayList. I then want to Pass this arrayList to another activity when a button is pressed. I've seen some examples of people storing string data but I need some help on how I would store "checked" HashMap objects in a listView into an ArrayList. So at the end all I want is an ArrayList that consists of objects (items) that were checked in the list which I can then pass.

What program goal is: allow user to select songs based on category and create their own custom playlist. The user will be presented songs for one category, they will select the songs they want from that category and then push a "Next" button which will send them to a new activity where they will be presented a new category of songs. At each category I am trying to store their selection and pass it along from activity(category) to activity(category). But the passing is not working. I could be doing something way off. Need some advice what or how to do. -Thanx

some code: Not the most organized I know. New to android so any pointers or things I should change

```
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.playlist);

    //final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsListData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    SongsManager plm = new SongsManager();
    // get all songs from sdcard
    this.songsList = plm.getPlayList();
    TextView label = new TextView(this);
    label.setText("Warm-up");
    label.setTextSize(16);
    label.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    label.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

    final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsListData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    // looping through playlist
    for(HashMap hs: songsList){
     if(hs.containsValue("Warm-up/cool down"))
    songsListData.add(hs);
     }

    // NEXT button
    Button btnLoadMore = new Button(this);
    btnLoadMore.setText("Next");
    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.addHeaderView(label);

// Adding Load More button to lisview at bottom
      lv.addFooterView(btnLoadMore);

    //List<Model> selectedlist = getModel(songsListData);
    ArrayAdapter<Model> adapter = new InteractiveArrayAdapter(this,
        getModel(songsListData));

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    //Listening to Load More button click event

    btnLoadMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
      String priorSongs = "priorSongs";
      List<Model> selSongs = getModel(songsListData);
      Intent i = new Intent(WarmUp.this, SlowWalking.class);
      i.putExtra(priorSongs, selSongs);
      startActivity(i); 
}
});

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
      int position, long id) {

     // getting listitem index
    int songIndex = position;

    // Starting new intent
    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity.class);
    in.putExtra("songIndex", songIndex);
    startActivity(in);
    finish();
            }
        });

    }
    private List<Model> getModel(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsListData) {
        List<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();
        for (HashMap<String, String> map : songsListData)
            for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet())
                 if (entry.getKey() == "songTitle")
                     list.add(get(entry.getValue()));

        // Initially select one of the items
        //list.get(1).setSelected(true);
        return list;
      }
```

Comment: *But the passing is not working* - how exactly does it fail?

Comment: I think it has something to do with the i.putExtra() method. I am trying to pass in a string and Serializable object. But List does not implement Serializable.

Answer (score 1):

You must create a class Adapter that extends a SimpleAdapter so it allows you to put all your hash map in your list view.